# async.parallel stops working on huge list of array

Tags: asynchronous, mongoose

i'm still new with async module. Basically, I want to do the batch update operation from array using async.parallel, like this :

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var async = require('async');
var list = req.body.dataArr; //the array
var asyncTasks = [];

_.each(hotelList,function(value,key){

    asyncTasks.push(function(callback){ 
            Hotel.find({hotelId:value.hotelId}).exec(function(err,hotels){
                if(err){
                   console.log(err);
                }
                if(hotels.length ==0){
                    //hotel not found
                    console.log('Hotel not found for ID :'+value.hotelId);
                    return;
                }

                hotels[0].countryCode = value.countryCode;
                hotels[0].city        = value.city;

                hotels[0].save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('saving failed ... Reason : '+err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('saving successful');
                });

            });
        });

}); 

async.parallelLimit(asyncTasks,function(){
//async.parallelLimit(asyncTasks,10, function(){
    console.log('finish call asyncTask');
    res.json({status:'success'});
});
```

The problem is, when i run it using all data in array (there's more then 100.000 indexes), it only stop without any message eventough i have waited for several minutes, but when i try to limit the array to only 10 using parallelLimit, it only do 10 update operation like this :

```
saving successful
```

Is there something wrong in how I'm using async? Sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `asyncTasks` functions need to call their `callback` parameters when they've finished their work so that `parallel` or `parallelLimit` knows when they're done.

```js
_.each(hotelList,function(value,key){

    asyncTasks.push(function(callback){ 
        Hotel.find({hotelId:value.hotelId}).exec(function(err,hotels){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
               return callback(err);
            }
            if(hotels.length ==0){
                //hotel not found
                console.log('Hotel not found for ID :'+value.hotelId);
                return callback(Error('Not found'));
            }

            hotels[0].countryCode = value.countryCode;
            hotels[0].city        = value.city;

            hotels[0].save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log('saving failed ... Reason : '+err);
                    return callback(err);
                }
                console.log('saving successful');
                callback();
            });
        });
    });
});
```